# How to deduce second parameter type from first parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, c++17

I am new to template-metaprogramming. The second parameter will be the same as the function parameter passed. I want to deduce the second parameter type from `Func`.

```
template<typename Func>
void execute(Func func, decltype(Func) t) 
{
    std::cout << func(t) << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    std::function<int(float)> func1 = [](float f) { return int(f); };
    execute(func1,1.5);
    return 0;
}
```

This works, but I don't want to declare additional `typenameme T` since the info is already available in `Func`, so why not deduce.

```
template<typename Func, typename T>
void execute(Func func, T t) 
{
    std::cout << func(t) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at variadic templates http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/EhvU7k9E/

Comment: Do you want to accept std::function only or any callable object? Do you want to accept a function with single argument only?

Comment: @Eugene: execute should accept a std::function and a second parameter as parameters

Comment: Why do not you want the additional template parameter?

Comment: @Eugene: The type info is already present in Func itself, I want to reduce from Func.

Comment: Why don't you write the first parameter as `std::function<Ret(Param)>`?

Comment: here the problem is that in `decltype(Func) t` the `Func` needs to know the argument type so that it can be used in this way `decltype(Func(arg)) t`

Comment: @JeJo: If you understand the question, can you edit it more?  The first version is invalid (`Func` is already a type and can’t go in `decltype`), and your comment suggests that `T` is supposed to be the *return* type.

Answer (score 3):

In your example there's no need to know the exact argument types, so the easiest solution here is to use a variadic template. Just take a parameter pack and forward them:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void execute(Func func, Args&&... a) {
    std::cout << func(std::forward<Args>(a)...) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto func1 = [](float f) { return int { f }; };
    execute(func1, 1.5);
    auto func2 = [](int i) { return float { i }; };
    execute(func2, 15);
    auto func3 = [](int a, int b, int c) { return a * b + c; };
    execute(func3, 3, 4, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I don't want to declare additional `typename T`* this does not pass the OP's requirement.

Comment: I read that. From the example given it's not obvious *why* that requirement is necessary. This is simply the easiest solution to the problem.

Comment: I think it is because of  this: *I want to deduce the second parameter type from Func*. However, OP did not mention what exactly the use-case.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to deduce the second parameter type from `Func`
>
> I don't want to declare additional `typename T`

I do not see any simple solution to your requirement, other than passing the callable object to the function, after [binding with the argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Following will make sure your second requirement and not need change your original code that much.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Func>
void execute(Func func) {
    std::cout << func() << std::endl;
}
int main() 
{
    auto func1 = std::bind([](float f) { return int(f); }, 2.5f);
    execute(func1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename> struct function_traits;

template <typename Function>
struct function_traits
    : public function_traits<decltype(
          &std::remove_reference<Function>::type::operator())> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Arguments>
struct function_traits<ReturnType (ClassType::*)(Arguments...) const>
    : function_traits<ReturnType (*)(Arguments...)> {};

/* support the non-const operator ()
 * this will work with user defined functors */
template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Arguments>
struct function_traits<ReturnType (ClassType::*)(Arguments...)>
    : function_traits<ReturnType (*)(Arguments...)> {};

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Arguments>
struct function_traits<ReturnType (*)(Arguments...)> {
  typedef ReturnType result_type;

  using argument_tuple = std::tuple<Arguments...>;
  template <std::size_t Index>
  using argument = typename std::tuple_element<Index, argument_tuple>::type;

  static const std::size_t arity = sizeof...(Arguments);
};

template <typename Function, std::size_t Index>
using nth_argument_type =
    typename function_traits<Function>::template argument<Index>;

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename FN>
void execute(FN func, nth_argument_type<FN,0> arg0) {
  std::cout << func(arg0) << std::endl;
};

int main() {
  int i = 7;
  auto fn = [](int a) { return a * a; };
  auto fn2 = [](int a) mutable { return a * a; };
  execute(fn, 5);
  execute(fn, i);
  execute(fn2, 5);
  execute(fn2, i);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You should **not** do this. If you do, your example will **stop working**, because your function is `int(float)`, but the argument is `double`.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Arg>
void execute(std::function<int(Arg)> func, Arg t) {
    std::cout << func(t) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::function<int(float)> func1 = [](float f) { return int(f); };
    execute(func1,1.5);
    return 0;
}
```

This won't compile. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6_Xzl9).

Stay with the T parameter, it is perfectly OK.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a type trait that provides access to the types used in a function signature. There isn't such a type trait included in the standard library. So you'll either need to use a library that implements one, or implement it yourself.

If you can use boost, they have exactly this implemented in their type traits: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html You would want to use the `argN_type` member to get the Nth argument's type.

If you can't use boost, you will need to implement your own type trait to make the argument types available. It might look like this:

```
// Base case for non-function types
template<typename T>
struct func_types { };

// Case for any generic function signature
template<typename Return, typename ...Args>
struct func_types<Return(Args...)>
{
    using ReturnType = Return;
    using ArgsTuple = std::tuple<Args...>;

    template<std::size_t N>
    struct args
    {
        using Type = std::tuple_element_t<N, ArgsTuple>;
    };
};

// Specialization for function pointers
template<typename Return, typename ...Args>
struct func_types<std::function<Return(Args...)>> : public func_types<Return(Args...)> { };

// Specialization for std::function
template<typename Return, typename ...Args>
struct func_types<std::function<Return(Args...)>> : public func_types<Return(Args...)> { };


// All further specializations for member functions,
// lambdas, etc. are left as an exercise to the reader

template<typename Func>
void execute(Func func, typename func_types<Func>::template args<0>::Type t)
{
    std::cout << func(t) << std::endl;
}
```

[This example is basically a stripped down version of this blog post](https://functionalcpp.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/function-traits/). This uses features added in C++14, so you would need to compile for that version, or newer.

Comment: Something like that @ark1974?